# Difficulty Adding Values and Array Lengths

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write some code to calculate an on base percentage. The program gathers the players name, year he has played on the team (size of array) and the year he started. Once I begin the array and start the information, if the user entered two years, I receive an error right at the second value because of the arrays length. How do I get around this issue? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

This is the error I receive: "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2"

I've tried creating variables for each item, adding and dividing to get the on base percentage. Once I do that, I can't seem to figure out how to print that out for each year. For example "Year 1985: -OBP-, Year 1986: -OBP-"

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public class RyanBaseballOBPArray
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int numYears;
    double [] years;
    String name;
    int startYear;
    double oBP;

     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.print("Enter name of baseball player: ");
     name = keyboard.nextLine();

     System.out.print("Enter the number of years " + name +" has been playing: ");
     numYears = keyboard.nextInt();

     years = new double[numYears];

     System.out.print("Enter " +name +" first year on the team: ");
     startYear = keyboard.nextInt();


     for (int index = 0; index < years.length; index++)
     { 
       System.out.print("For Year " + (index +1 ) + "\nEnter number of hits: ");
       years[1] = keyboard.nextInt();


       System.out.print("For Year " + (index +1) + "\nEnter number of walks: ");
       years[2] = keyboard.nextInt();



       System.out.print("For Year" + (index +1) + "\nEnter the number of times player"
                          + "has been hit by a pitch:");
       years[3] = keyboard.nextInt();

       System.out.print("For Year" + (index +1) + "\nEnter the number of at bats:");
       years[4] = keyboard.nextInt();

       System.out.print("For Year" + (index +1) + "\nEnter the number of sacrafice flies" 
                          + "that year: ");
       years[5] = keyboard.nextInt();

       years[0] = (years[1] + years[2] + years[3]) / years[4] + years[2] + years[3] + years[5];

     }
     printOnBasePercentage(name, startYear, years);   
  }
  public static void printOnBasePercentage(String name, int startYear, double []years){
    System.out.println(name + "'s On Base Percentage");

    System.out.println(years[0]);


  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue stems from the fact you have hard-coded array access to the years array whose length is defined by keyboard input.

```
years[5] = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Thus if someone only plays for 3 years there are only 3 elements in the year array, and you are trying to access the 6th giving you an out of bounds exception.

Comment: What would you suggest I do to correctly set the length of the array? Thank you.

Comment: From the looks of things you are putting the keyboard input into an array that currently on has the number of years. You could make a Year class that holds variables for all the questions that you are asking each year. Then use an Arraylist<Year> and add the answers to the year object.